# Why i cant use AlertDialog within onPrimaryClipChanged?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, clipboardmanager

I have a program that monitors clipboard by getting copied text to the clipboard
I want each time user copies some text to the clipboard i print it
first i have used `Toast` to print the copied text by the user and it works fine
but when i want to print the copied text in an `AlertDialog` it say "Unfortunately your program has stooped"
What i do to print that text in an alert box?

here is the Activity that monitors the clipboard text

```
package on.boot.completed;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public class OnTextChanged extends Activity  implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener{

        ClipboardManager clipBoard;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( this );

        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

            /* it works fine!!!!
             * 
            Toast.makeText(this, clipBoard.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            */

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
            alertDialog.setMessage(clipBoard.getText()+"");
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("OK", null);  
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

And here is my Service that runs at the background

```
package on.boot.completed;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class StarterService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
    /**
     * The started service opens the Activity.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OnTextChanged.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intents);
    }
}
```

And here is my Log cat Message

```
11-23 15:39:30.180: I/dalvikvm(2281): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
11-23 15:39:30.256: D/(2281): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb925f780, tid 2281
11-23 15:39:37.460: D/dalvikvm(2281): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 3% free 11063K/11335K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 3ms
11-23 15:39:37.468: D/AndroidRuntime(2281): Shutting down VM
11-23 15:39:37.468: W/dalvikvm(2281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6227288)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@53658204 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at on.boot.completed.OnTextChanged.onPrimaryClipChanged(OnTextChanged.java:39)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.content.ClipboardManager.reportPrimaryClipChanged(ClipboardManager.java:230)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.content.ClipboardManager$2.handleMessage(ClipboardManager.java:75)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-23 15:39:37.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note that iam using Emulator to test m program, Iam not using real device

Comment: Show crash logs from LogCat if application showing `"Unfortunately your program has stooped"` message

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK see updates ....

Comment: It seems that the Activity has finished?